# On the trivialisation map of principal G-bundles in overlapping regions of the base manifold.

Tags: manifolds, principal-bundles

The lecture notes I am reading state that given a principal G-bundle $P\overset{\pi}{\rightarrow} M$, if we are given two patches on the base manifold $U_\alpha$ and $U_\beta$ we have two distinct trivialising maps acting on the fibres over the points in the overlap, $U_{\alpha\beta}=U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta}$: $$\psi_\alpha:\pi^{-1}(U_{\alpha\beta})\rightarrow U_{\alpha\beta}\times G, \tag{1}$$ and $$\psi_\beta:\pi^{-1}(U_{\alpha\beta})\rightarrow U_{\alpha\beta}\times G. \tag{2}$$ What is strange to me is that, while these trivialising maps of course map to the same point $m\in U_{\alpha\beta}$, the point $g\in G$ is not necessarily the same. In other words $\psi_\alpha(p)=(m,g_\alpha)$ and $\psi_\beta(p)=(m,g_\beta)$ such that $g_\alpha\neq g_\beta$, it is strange to me that locally, the point $p\in P$ can be locally associated with a different pair $(m,g)$ depending on which patch containing $m$ we are considering on the base manifold.

*Disclaimer: I'm a physicist not a mathematician.*

Comment: This is because $U_{\alpha}\times G$ is not a subset of $P$: it is a way of looking at a subset of $P$. $\psi_{\alpha}$ is a sort of glasses that allow you to look at $P$ locally like a product $U_{\alpha}\times G$. If you change your glasses, say $\psi_{\beta}$, you may see something that is globally the same but with another appearance. The change of glasses $\psi_{\alpha}\circ \psi_{\beta}^{-1}$ allows you to understand the correspondance between the two glasses. For example, blue in the glasses $\alpha$ is equal to red for glasses $\beta$.

Comment: @DIdier_ So I should *not* think of $P$ as being "like $M\times G$ with more interesting global structure". A non-trivial $P$ cannot be thought of globally as "$G$ attached to $M$"? In a similar way to the fact that a manifold's properties can look very different in two charts, the total space of the principal bundle can look very different in two local trivialisation?

Comment: Exactly. It is locally $G$ attached to $M$, but not a global gluing. For example, the mobius strip is locally the same thing as gluing an inteval to a part of the circle, but the twist makes it not a global gluing of an interval over a circle (it would be a cylinder otherwise). In this particular case, the change of glasses $\psi_{\alpha}\circ\psi_{\beta}^{-1}$ will say "upside down" in the fiber (the interval)

Comment: @DIdier_ Understood, thank you!